# How do I use service proxy with vertx fabric8 plugin

Tags: java, xml, vert.x

I'm trying to use vertx-service-proxy as described in the guide for Java devs tutorial.
In it, it says I need to add the following to my pom:

```
<annotationProcessors>
  <annotationProcessor>io.vertx.codegen.CodeGenProcessor</annotationProcessor>
</annotationProcessors>
<generatedSourcesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/generated</generatedSourcesDirectory>
<compilerArgs>
  <arg>-AoutputDirectory=${project.basedir}/src/main</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

However, I want to use the fabric8 vertx-maven-plugin, instead of the maven compiler plugin. Is it possible to use the fabric8 vertx-maven-plugin and use vertx-service-proxy? Where would I put the codegen annotationProcessors section?

This is what my build plugin looks like:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>vmp</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>initialize</goal>
                        <goal>package</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <redeploy>true</redeploy>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried adding the annotationProcessors tag in the configuration tag above, but it was not valid.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I should've read the documentation more before I posted..

I just needed to add `<classifier>processor</classifier>` to my pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
  <artifactId>vertx-service-proxy</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.0</version>
  <classifier>processor</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Then I also needed to define a `package-info.java` file where my Service class was located.
After that, the proxies generated fine, even using the fabric8 vertx-maven-plugin.

Comment: Actually, with or without the Fabric8 Maven plugin, there's no compilation without the Maven compiler plugin.

Comment: That's true.. but with the Fabric8 maven plugin, I don't have to explicitly define the maven-compiler-plugin in my pom. I'm sure the vertx-maven-plugin is pulling it in automatically behind the scenes.